# Why does my for loop in R only saves the last iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to save differents plots in this vector but it saves me the last iteration in all the cases. The extrange thing is that the title change as it should. Thanks!

```
pl1=vector("list",5)
for (i in 1:5) {
  pl1[[i]]=ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=c(1:96),y=G1[[i]]),color="blue")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(0, 24, 3),expand = c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks =seq(1, 8, 0.8))+
    labs(title=ubi[i,3],x="Dias(hs)",y= "Pp(mm/hs)")+
    theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid = element_line(color="white"))
  }
```

Comment: What is `length(pl1)` of your object? If it's 5, then all the ggplot items are saved in the list.

Comment: The plot is only build when you `print` it. Since you don't print within the `for` loop, `i` equals 5 when you print (except if you change the value of `i` in between running the loop and printing the plot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `local` and `print`.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
 
  pl1[[i]] <- local({ 
    i <- i
    p1 <- ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=c(1:96),y=G1[[i]]),color="blue")+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(0, 24, 3),expand = c(0,0))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks =seq(1, 8, 0.8))+
      labs(title=ubi[i,3],x="Dias(hs)",y= "Pp(mm/hs)")+
      theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid = element_line(color="white"))
    print(p1)})
}
```